# Unable to deploy to heroku

Tags: git, deployment, heroku

I'm trying to deploy app into Heroku and it shows invalid path. I already have `git@heroku.com:chat-app` setup correctly.

```
C:\Users\Umabharathi\Nodejs\chat-app>git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:chat-app (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:chat-app (push)
origin  https://github.com/Umabharathi-G/chat-app.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Umabharathi-G/chat-app.git (push)

C:\Users\Umabharathi\Nodejs\chat-app>git push heroku master

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
 !
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: 71:fc:12:91:62:53:9d:0f:eb:f2:9a:7c:97:64:15:54

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Given, that you've proper Heroku CLI installed on your system, and you've logged into Heroku CLI and have initialized a git repo with `git init` command, the following should work for you:

You should create an application first on heroku with `heroku create UmabharathiChatApp` 
 - Make sure the app name you create is unique

This will give you a url and a git repo.

Next `git add .` to add all the files for staging

commit your stage with `git commit -m "first commit"`

To push these commits onto your git repo, you need to have a remote connection - This is a one time setup command: `heroku git:remote -a UmabharathiChatApp`

Now you're all set, just push the commits with a `git push heroku master` and you'll be good!

Comment: Just had another look over your command prompt, it seems like you've not properly set your Heroku CLI. Just in case, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up